# Adding Throttle to jQuery Bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I have been trying to add a throttle to this function but nothing seems to work, is there a jQuery code for throttling so I can slow this from firing so fast?

```
jQuery('#product-mainimage').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {    
    var dirs = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down';
    scrollangle(dirs);
    return false;    
});
```

Comment: I assume you want to slow down scrolling, correct?

Comment: @AdamAzad I am using 'jQuery Mousewheel', there is a glitch where using a laptop mouse makes it fire very fast so i would like to slow that down